# fail to install ubuntu server 14.04 64bit LTS from USB drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, usb-drive

I created a bootable USB using Startup disk creator (in ubuntu desktop 12.04 32bit), from an iso image  of Ubuntu server 14.04 64 bit, when I want to boot another computer using this usb drive, The computer boots up, the installation process ok, it gets through the selecting the language, then it shows me the error that it can't mount the cd-rom to continue the installation, I tried several times with others USB devices but it shows me the same error.
How can I get this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using anther iso image !! I changed this image `ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso` and used this one `ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso`, and it worked like a charm using the same startup disk creator and the same USB. finally I think this is a bug in that version of ubuntu server, because I'm not the only one who get this error.

Comment: There is no ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso - there is a ...amd64+mac.iso which I am assuming is equivalent. I also tried the umount advice which did get me past the initial error, but then "Unable to find 'pool/main/l/linux-lts-utopic/block-modules-3.16.0-generic-di_3_10.0.40~10.04.1_amd64.udeb' came up. 14.04.2 doesn't seem USB friendly at all :/

Answer (score 44):

This is how i got it to work.

When it gets the CD-ROM error, move the install USB stick from one port, to another USB port on your PC. Then retry.

This worked. I don't know why.

Not only that but I was reinstalling 14.04 later that night, and the CD-ROM error did not happen again. The 2nd install went without a hitch.

Yes it worked for me also.

Comment: I'm to confirm that the "switch USB port" trick works on my machine. Very weird...

Comment: Yes this worked for me too!

Comment: Amazing fix - worked a treat with `14.04.3 server amd64` too

Comment: worked for me as well

Comment: That's very weird, worked for me too.

Comment: Best fix ever :D

Comment: Did not work for me, unfortunately (Ubuntu Server 15.10)

Comment: While this isn't the best solution, it gets my vote simply because it involves less effort. I'm installing Ubuntu Server, I don't need any extra weird hoops to jump through, after all ;-)

Comment: worked for me as well very well

Comment: Worked for me on 14.04.4

Comment: Worked for me 16.04.3 server

Answer (score 16):

Problem is that the new image isn't meant to be used with unetbootin or any of the normal USB creators.

Just use `dd` like:

```
dd if=ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=16M
```

(obviously, replace `/dev/sdb` with the path to your USB key, but don't use any partitions (i.e. don't use `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`, etc -- just the whole device)

Comment: This appears to be the most correct answer and doesn't require any mucking around.

Comment: This is what I did (in ubuntu server 15.10) but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Works perfectly! For OS X, use `sudo dd if=ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/rdiskX`. Check for USB drive using `diskutil list`.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it's useless if you don't have a existing linux install.

Comment: resource busy on OSX? http://goo.gl/6rZFpv

Comment: well, on OSX this tutorial helped me a lot: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-for-pc-on-a-mac--cms-21187

Comment: @SpacenJasset It does appear to be the most correct answer. But in my case it just didn't work.

Comment: Works! @FakeName Rufus can DD images (it asks if you want to do a file copy or an image copy) - https://rufus.akeo.ie/.

Answer (score 13):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253860 has an answer.

Here are the steps that I took to get it to work

1. When you get the error, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to a second console.
2. Find out which device your USB stick is (`tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog`)
3. If the device is busy, umount it (umount /dev/sd[abcdef]1)
4. Then mount it to `/cdrom` (`mount -t vfat /dev/sd[abcdef]1 /cdrom`)
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get back to the install console, and try detecting again

Comment: Thank you for your question, I tried something like this, I did Alt-F2 to open a console, I tried to mount the USB myself by the command, but it failed and show me the same error.
At the end I solve this by using anther iso image !! I changed this image `ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso` and used this one `ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso`, and it worked like a charm using the same startup disk creator and the same USB. finally I think this is a bug in that version of ubuntu server, because I'm not the only one who get this error.

Comment: This worked for me, however I had to exit the CD-ROM detection first by hitting "no" to stop retrying. Then, alt-f2 and mount the usb to /cdrom. Then, this is the key part, alt-f1 back and select the menu step AFTER "detect cd-rom". It skips auto detection and just keeps on going with whatever you've just mounted into /cdrom

Comment: @Monkpit Your comment got me further than any of the answers. But upon finishing the install I am now left with a system configured to only install packages from cdrom, which means it won't download packages from the Ubuntu repositories, which is what I really need.

Answer (score 5):

With the installation CD `ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso` I ran into the same issue, for me it was as easy as running: `umount /dev/sdc1`

My `tail -n 20 /var/log/syslog` showed that the installer tried multiple times to mount `/dev/sdc1` but since it was already mounted to `/media` that obviously failed.

With the above command I unmounted the USB-CD-Drive and the following attempt to automatically mount succeeded right away. After <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> just check what is currently mounted by issuing `mount` in the command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

The steps here:

1. At the third screen (don't wait until the next screen), hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, Enter
2. Type: `df -h` to get information where is USB flash disk located/ mounted. in eg.: "/dev/sda1" mount as "/media"
3. Type command `mount -t iso9660 /media/ubuntu.iso /cdrom -o ro,loop`
4. Then hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to back at main screen of installation
5. Finish. Now you can continue your process installation as usually.

The source is [here...](http://www.cyberscie.com/2015/07/error-install-ubuntu-server-desktop.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem as well with `ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso`. Unmounting the /sda/ drive from /media and remounting it as /cdrom worked but I ran into installation error further down the line when it was trying to extract files for the install. The USB drive I was trying to install from was created with Linux Live (LILI) USB creator. I recreated the usb installer with Universal USB installer from PenDriveLinux and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Install GRUB2 on USB to boot Ubuntu Linux ISO

Another benefit is you can setup the GRUB2 to boot from different ISO. [See *Multi-ISO* below]

Steps See [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-grub2-on-usb-from-ubuntu-linux/) for details

Install GRUB2 to USB (assume the USB drive is on /dev/`sdx1` partition)

1. `sudo mkdir /mnt/USB && sudo mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt/USB`
2. `sudo grub-install --force --removable --boot-directory=/mnt/USB/boot /dev/sdx`
3. `cd /mnt/USB/boot/grub`
4. `wget pendrivelinux.com/downloads/grub.cfg` [1]
5. download the iso you want and rename it to `/mnt/USB/ubuntu.iso`. Make sure it's named `ubuntu.iso` and not the original `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso`

Note: If you are using a 64-bit ISO, then you need to modify the grub.cfg. 
See [1] below for detail

Done. You should be able to boot your machine with the USB.

[1] Here the content of the grub.cfg

```
set timeout=10
set default=0

menuentry "Run Ubuntu Live ISO" {
 loopback loop /ubuntu.iso
 linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu.iso splash --
 initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

64-bit ISO's `vmlinuz` is named `vmlinuz.efi`. so line 6 of the grub.cfg will be

```
 linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu.iso splash --
```

## Multi-ISO

1. Put your ISO (e.g. `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`) in `/mnt/USB/`
2. Add a `menuentry` to grub.cfg with the correct ISO name

> ```
> menuentry "Run Ubuntu 16.04.1 Live ISO" {
>  loopback loop /ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
>  linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso splash --
>  initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
> }
> ```

Comment: but this method not going to work with Ubuntu server CDs

Answer (score 0):

### mkusb works in and with Ubuntu Server as well as Ubuntu Desktop

- mkusb version 12 alias **`dus`** works in text mode, so you can use it also when running Ubuntu Server via its console or remotely via ssh.

  [image]
- mkusb version 12 alias **`dus`** works in graphics mode in standard Ubuntu (Desktop).

  [image]

  [image]
- mkusb uses `dd` under the hood to clone linux hybrid iso files to a USB drive or memory card. This is a reliable method to create a boot drive, and all current Ubuntu iso files are hybrid iso files, including mini.iso and the Ubuntu Server iso files.
- `dd` is straightforward, very powerful but also very dangerous. You can easily overwrite valuable data by writing to the wrong drive. mkusb wraps a safety belt around `dd`.
- **Install mkusb with the following command lines**

  If you run standard Ubuntu, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
  ```
- **Lean alternative in Ubuntu Server: install only mkusb-nox**

  `mkusb-nox` is a command line tool, that also wraps security around `dd`, and that does not want to install a lot of extra program packages, only `pv`.

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mkusb-nox
  ```

  Run `mkusb-nox` for example with the following command line

  ```
  sudo mkusb-nox ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso
  ```

  The manual provides more details,

  ```
  man mkusb-nox
  ```

### Links

- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [image]
- [alternate link to the quick start manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf)
- [**`mkusb-nox`** quick start manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-nox.pdf)