# ubuntu install not working - hanging because trying to mount installation usb

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb

So I did something really stupid and because of that I need to reinstall ubuntu. So I downloaded the iso, used this command to put it on the usb:

```
dd if=ubuntu-iso.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=16M
```

which I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593002/fail-to-install-ubuntu-server-14-04-64bit-lts-from-usb-drive). (Just for reference I also just tried doing it the normal way using `Disk Image Writer`.

I then booted up into the usb/live cd thing and clicked install ubuntu. It them lets me get to the point where I can say that I want it to download updates and 3rd party stuff. (which I tried both selecting and not selecting) and then it gets stuck there loading for a long time. So then I rebooted into the ***Try Ubuntu*** thing, and after it froze again at that same screen I quit the program and retried it, after which it let me get through.

Then I go through the rest of the steps and it starts

```
Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda)...
```

At which it sits for a while, so I opened up the console thing underneath it, where it is stuck at:

```
ubuntu-gnome systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

Eventually the computer falls asleep and when I *wake it up* it has this message:

```
ubuntu-gnome gnome-session[1382]: Gjs-Message JS LOG: Unable to mount volume Ubuntu-GNOME 15.10 amd64: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Error mounting /dev/sdb1 ... /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

`/dev/sdb1` is the usb that I created earlier

I have no idea what's happening here. Any help in the right direction would be wonderful. If you need any more information, I would be happy to give it to you. So just ask. Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Test RAM, It could not be the case but I had this problems when I had bad RAM.  When the Live USB is booting hit ESC and pick the "Test memory" option just to make sure it is not the case.