# How to install Ubuntu Server 16.04 from USB (without cdrom)?

Tags: server, 16.04, system-installation, usb

I have created a bootable USB media (external USB drive, not an USB stick) from the 64bit Ubuntu Server 16.04 ISO image. Various tutorials explain how to do this. This time I used rufus from windows 10 using this tutorial: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

However, the 16.04 server installation is hardcoded to work on /cdrom which, obviously, does not exist. The installation does not work.
[image]
[image]

I found this (old) thread, but the tricks described did not help.
[fail to install ubuntu server 14.04 64bit LTS from USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593002/fail-to-install-ubuntu-server-14-04-64bit-lts-from-usb-drive)

I also searched for other alternatives (like installing over the network), but I could not find an easy solution. It seems quite outdated to hardcode the installation path to a hardware device (remember floppy drives?).

What is the easiest way to install Ubuntu Server 16.04 without a CD ROM?

Comment: How did you create the USB stick?  The 'hardcoded' `cdrom` is actually not just the CDRom, but the ISO, and I've done numerous server installs from USB so I know it works out of the box.  Depending on how you create the USB stick depends on how the system 'boots' to the installer (and it works fine via USB)

Comment: The 16.04 is not hard coded to work **only** with CDROMs.  Very few people are using CDROMs for their installations as compared to the LiveUSB.  Where did you get your ISO and how did you create the USB stick.

Comment: I used rufus (from windows 10), as described on the official ubuntu site (I just added the link in my question). Before, I tried with Win32 DiskImager (iirc) with the exact same result. It boots just fine, but /cdrom is not there.

Comment: Yes, it is hardcoded to search installation resources on /cdrom. I've downloaded the latest server iso from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server

Comment: Are you trying to install to an EFI disk?  Does your Drive already have an OS, if so which OS?

Comment: I'm not sure what EFI means, but the server does not run an UEFI bios. Currently it runs an Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop upgraded from 14.04. There is only one SSD drive with 2+1 partitions os,home+swap.

Comment: Thomas Ward, is it possible that the external USB drive is mounted differently than USB sticks? I'll find a stick and try, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the key problem is the "external USB drive". I did the exact same thing with an "USB stick" and it works out of the box. It seems the USB stick is mounted differently and redirection to the ISO works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the same thing. Burn the ISO using RUFUS with a USB stick instead. Make sure you select the proper OS in RUFUS. Curious to see if it works out. Let us know.