# Create a Ubuntu Server bootable USB doesn't work using Startup Disk Creator or dd

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, usb, dd

These instructions (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) doesn't work for Ubuntu Server iso. Doing dd if=ubuntuserver.iso of=/dev/sdb neither. In both situations, after installer boots correctly, it claims it doesn't found any CD drive and stops.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried unetbootin? You can find the details here: https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html

Comment: Thanks but yes, I've tried, with the same problem. Here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/593002/fail-to-install-ubuntu-server-14-04-64bit-lts-from-usb-drive) there is much more discussion about the issue, but none of the proposed solutions works for mie (I'm using the 16.04 version)

Comment: Well, http://askubuntu.com/questions/847025/create-an-ubuntu-server-bootable-usb-doesnt-work is about doing things "manually" step by step. This issue is the same but using direct tools.

Comment: SDC and Unetbootin do not seem to work well with 16.04. I have switched to mkusb, but have not tried it with Server yet.