# Create an Ubuntu Server bootable USB doesn't work

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, live-usb, iso

These instructions (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) doesn't work for Ubuntu Server iso. Doing `dd if=ubuntuserver.iso of=/dev/sdb` doesn't work either. In both situations, after the Ubuntu Server installer boots correctly, it says it hasn't found any CD drive and stops.

I've a USB stick where I've put the content of Ubuntu Server iso on it. I've configured Syslinux (with no APPEND parameter) pointing to vmlinuz+initrd present in "install" folder. The installer boots correctly but it hangs with an error saying it doesn't find the CD-ROM.

If I replace the vmlinuz+initrd with the "hd-media" ones (available [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/)) I get another error: installer can't find any iso file anywhere (which is logical because I don't have any iso, I have the expanded tree on sdb1).

So I can't boot Ubuntu Server 16.04 from a USB stick.

Comment: Thanks, but with Ubuntu minimal CD the packages must be downloaded from a remote server. I don't want to have any network infrastructure: I just want to insert the Usb, install Ubuntu and nothing more.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: I finally solved using a Fedora Server iso  :-(

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I ended up using an actual CDROM instead of a USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Cloning*** the current Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS iso files with ***dd*** works for me. But I use [mkusb or mkusb-nox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to wrap a safety belt around that powerful but dangerous *dd* tool.

- Maybe the original 16.04 version is bad. But **16.04.1** (the first point release) is debugged and polished.
- Maybe your download {was/is/will be} bad. Please check the **md5sum** (or get a new copy via torrent, that checks the md5sum automatically).

  ```
  d2d939ca0e65816790375f6826e4032f *ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso
  455206c599c25d6a576ba23ca906741a *ubuntu-16.04.1-server-i386.iso
  ```

-o-

*If you want an **installed** system in your USB stick*, I suggest that you try according to the following link,

[Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)